# I am not able to receive emails on my VPS

Tags: debian, email, dns, vps

I am using linux (Debian 8) on my VPS server. I use virtualmin to handle all domains. I created emails using 'create new user' in the 'edit users' section. I can send emails to others, but I am not able to receive emails.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What have you done to tell external systems to deliver email for your domains to your VPS?

Comment: can you please tell me what am i supposed to do?  i have not done anything more than this.

Comment: DNS MX records. Ensuring port 25 is open on your server.

Comment: I use cloudflare. I have added an mx entry pointing to mail.mydomain.com. I have not done anything for port 25. how to open that port?

Comment: Do you ever search for questions that others just maybe already have had?

Comment: @Panki, i have tried many solutions but none of them is working. below is one of them.     sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT

Comment: below is error, i am getting

Comment: DNS Error: 6999304 DNS type 'mx' lookup of mydomain.com. responded with code NOERROR 6999304 DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of mail.mydomain.com. responded with code NXDOMAIN 6999304 DNS type 'a' lookup of mail.mydomain.com. responded with code NXDOMAIN

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new information, and format it (with the formatting buttons) as appropriate. For example these errors could be formatted as code with the `{}` button. Make it easy for us to read your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the email issue by Configuring Postfix to not use ipv6. belos is way to do that.

add below line in your /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

and restart postfix using below command

```
systemctl restart postfix
```

i find above solution at below thread
https://www.virtualmin.com/node/53447